# SFDX Source Diff: Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

#### Background

I want to use the `Source Diff` feature in VSCode.

When I follow the [instructions](https://forcedotcom.github.io/salesforcedx-vscode/articles/user-guide/source-diff) to install it, by running this command:

`sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-diff`

I get this error:

```
$ sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-diff
This plugin is not digitally signed and its authenticity cannot be verified. Continue installation y/n?: y
Finished digital signature check.
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
    at Object.readSync (fs.js:493:3)
    at tryReadSync (fs.js:332:20)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:369:19)
    at onUnexpectedError (C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.22.0-de5c6ecff8\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:91833:100)
    at C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.22.0-de5c6ecff8\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:91936:9
Installing plugin @salesforce/sfdx-diff... !
Error: yarn add @salesforce/sfdx-diff@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:C:/Users/Robert/AppData/Local/sfdx/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=C:/Users/Robert/AppData/Local/sfdx/yarn --check-files exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.forked.on (C:/Users/Robert/AppData/Local/sfdx/client/7.22.0-de5c6ecff8/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-plugins/lib/yarn.js:31:28)
```

#### Additional information

```
Version: 1.38.0 (user setup)
Commit: 3db7e09f3b61f915d03bbfa58e258d6eee843f35
Date: 2019-09-03T21:49:13.459Z
Electron: 4.2.10
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.17763

sfdx --version
sfdx-cli/7.22.0-de5c6ecff8 win32-x64 node-v10.15.3
```

#### Questions

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. How do I fix it?

Comment: this could be helpful [link](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4336).